# Good Software That Can be Used to Make Operating System for Commercial (With Document)

Tags: linux, operating-system

I’m currently looking into Gentoo Linux. However I’m not very proficient in regards to laws. I’d like to knows the effective way to make my own operating system without having to make it open source. If possible, I’d love to see the statement that declared so in the official document too.

Comment: This is not really a request for software, as much a request for advice on how to create an OS, which is off-topic for this site, and well outside the capability to answer easily on any StackExchange site.

Comment: Possibly [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) or [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) could give advice about forking a Linux, but AFAIK, they all require attribution, and many/most open source licenses won't let you close a fork, though some will.

Comment: "`make my own operating system without having to make it open source`" - code  it from scratch? That's worked well for Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to modify the source code for an OS without revealing your source code changes, then you cannot use Linux. The [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL) license they use requires you to make your source code available to anyone receiving your changed software.

(Well, you can make changes for yourself only, but you cannot distribute copies, or ship [products containing that modified code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoization).)

## BSD

You would need an open-source OS with a more permissive license. The obvious choice is [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution).

They welcome contributed changes that might be an improvement to BSD, but you are not obligated to contribute back to the project nor to provide source code to those receiving your software.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).